# Звуковые библиотеки для Android

Tags: android, аудио, звукозапись

**Суть проблемы -**
SoundPool не проигрывает звуки длинее 5ти секунд.
MediaPlayer имеет недопустимую задержку воспроизведения.
Стандартными методами нельзя сделать запись выходного звука из приложения в wav или mp3 файл, например.

**Вопрос -**
Не подскажете какую нибудь sound библиотеку которая сможет решить выше поставленные проблемы, зарание большое спасибо! =)

Answer (score 1):

На вопрос ответить полностью не могу, но если надо записать звук в mp3, то используйте Lame кодек.
https://github.com/yhirano/SimpleLameLibForAndroid

Comment: Это для записи из микрофона или output звукового канала проги?